# How to find this maximum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How to find the maximum of
$$f = |x_1x_3 + x_1x_4 + x_2x_3 -x_2x_4|$$
on the four-dimensional cube $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4:|x_k| \le 1,
1 \le k \le 4\}$? Calculations with CASes suggest it equals 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that taking absolute is not necessary, as it doesn't change your result (why?).

We are now trying to maximize a linear function in each of your variables $x_i$. Let us start by writing $g(x_1)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, where you can change $x_1$ and see the others as parameters. Now if you think of this as a straight line (or, more generally, any convex function) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it will assume it's maximum on the side points of any fixed interval. Meaning, given arbitrary $x_2,x_3,x_4$, our function $g(x_1)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ will assume it's greatest value at $x_1=\pm 1$.

Since you can do the very same for $x_2,...,x_4$, you are left with a total of $16$ cases, which are a bit of a pain to work through but not all that bad.

**Edit:** Why can we leave out the modulus:

There's basically two options here:

1) Let us suppose we have found a quadruplet $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that $f(x)$ assumes it's maximum. The original $f$, so the absolute value. Let us look at $g$, which is $f$ without the modulus. We want to show that the maximum value of $f$ is the same as that of $g$.

We can note that $g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=-g(-x_1,-x_2,x_3,x_4)$, and $f(x)=g(x)\iff g(x)\geq 0$.

Now suppose that we have an $x$ such that $f(x)$ assumes it's max. Then there's two possibilities: Either $g(x)>0$, in which case $g(x)$ is a maximum of $g$ (note that $f\geq g$, hence we cannot have any greater value for $g$). Or $g(x)<0$, in which case we can substitute $\overline{x}=(-x_1,-x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and have $f(\overline{x})=f(x)$, while $g(\overline{x})=-g(x)>0$, and since this kind of transformation will never make us leave our defined cube where $|x_i|\leq 1$, we are done.

2) Possibly a more pragmatic approach: Everything above is true for a maximum as well as a minimum. So, while we know that $g$ will assume it's maximum value at least for one quadruplet of the form $x_i=\pm 1$, the same also holds for the minimum value. So, since we are going to test all these possible cases anyway, we can look at the absolute of the maximum value of $g$, we can look at the absolute of the minimum value of $g$, and decide which of these is greater.

Comment: @ Some Math Student: Thank you for your interest to the question and very quick response. Can you kindly present a concrete solution, of course, basing it?

Comment: @ Markiyan Hirnyk: Are you sure those few dozen solutions are not just due to Maple being  a bit imprecise? I put that monstrum into Wolfram and got $f=1.999999999989390039780033205902672$, which is obviously not the same as $2$.Changing $x_1$ to $1$ yielded, in fact, $1.999999999998236839780025240243952$, which is a bit larger (have fun counting $9$s) - not that this is a proof, for that see above, but I believe your mass of solutions is a consequence of Maple not calculating accurately enough.

Comment: @ Some Math Student: Maple produces a few dozen solutions, in particular, $[x_1=−0.9999999999955766,x_2=−0.18895471900221006,x_3=−0.9999999999991992,x_4=−0.9999999999997611],$ As far as I understand it, this contradicts your "proof".

Comment: @ Markiyan Hirnyk: Since somehow I seem to have posted my reply before your question: see above. The set of numbers where the numberical error is small enough that Maple will give you $2$ as a result is probably quite large, but that is due to Maple being too imprecise. Again, if you put the above numbers into Wolfram and change $x_2$ to $-1$, your result will increase. By an amount close to $10^{-10}$, but still.

Comment: @ Some Math Student: How about the solution $[x_1 = -1, x_2 = 1, x_3 = 0, x_4 = -1]$?

Comment: @ Markiyan Hirnyk: Now that one is clever. Let's just look at what happens here. If we say $g(x_3)=f(-1,1,x_3,-1)$, we have $g(x_3)=-x_3+1+x_3+1=2$, which is not dependant on $x_3$. So, indeed, $g$ is a straight line, but it is parallel to the $x_3$-axis, hence it doesn't matter which value for $x_3$ you put in. Meaning, $\pm 1$ works as well.
So, $x_i=\pm 1$ will not get you all quadruples where our function is maximized, but we still have that there must be a quadruplet such that $x_i=\pm 1$ and f assumes its maximum, which is all I stated.

Comment: @ Some Math Student: Summarizing, the set of the optimal solutions seems to be infinite. I find your idea productive. However, I don't see any complete answer of you to the question under consideration.

Comment: @ Markiyan Hirynk: What my proof did was show that there is a quadruplet $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that $x_i=\pm 1\quad \forall i$, such that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ assumes it's maximum. Which, in turn, means all you have to do is try the $16$ possible cases for $x_i$. Since you asked for the maximum, and not the set of numbers such that the maximum value is reached, I'm not sure what exactly more you want?

Comment: @ Some Math Student: Agree. Can you explain in detail why the modulus in the objective function may be omitted?

Comment: @ Markiyan Hirnyk: Added that part. If you still need any of my comments, since this discussion is getting kind of long, be ware that I will delete them in the near future. Just letting you know :)